# SQL Server 2000 RPC inside transaction

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2000, rpc, linked-server

I have created a linked server to from SQL Server 2000 to SQL Server 2008 R2.
And I am making RPC call inside a stored procedures as below.

```
--successful without transaction
execute sql2008server.DBName.dbo.sp_in_sql2008 @param1...,@paramn
-- end successful without transaction
```

This works successfully, however the same RPC call fails from with in a Transaction as shown below.

```
-- Below call fails
BEGIN TRANSACTION 'someTran'
--some lines of statements
execute sql2008server.DBName.dbo.sp_in_sql2008 @param1...,@paramn
END
```

The remote stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 has a transaction inside it.

So SQL Server 2000 doesn't allow nested transaction in RPC?

Or it doesn't allow RPC inside a transaction at all?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Ramesh.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I am not getting any error. My application freezes for few minutes. Data not getting inserterd in DB. when I debug, I found that the RPC statement doesnt even execute.